# Prawn - image is cropped & full image not render

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, prawn

I'm currently working on a Ruby on Rails 5.2 application using Prawn and CombinePDF. I make a request to get a file to the Box api. The file I get from box I then convert to string using `StringIO.new(image)` which I then add to a prawn document as shown.

```
attach_docs_from_submission(user_data).each do |file|
      image = client.download_file(file)
      format_image = StringIO.new(image)
      pdf_prawn = Prawn::Document.new
      pdf_prawn.image format_image
      pdf_data = pdf_prawn.render
      pdf << CombinePDF.parse(pdf_data)
    end
```

However, when I check the PDF is not the full image. [image]

Is there a way to fit full size of image? is the issue coming from Prawn or CombinePDF?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on my preference since I realized there are many ways to go about this. For me personally this is the most lean and flexible solution.

```
      pdf_prawn = Prawn::Document.new(page_size: 'LETTER')
      pdf_prawn.image format_image, fit: [610, 790],
                                    position: :center,
                                    position: :center
```

So you set `page_size` to `LETTER` and then you get the dimensions of letter and pass those as the arguments to `fit:` taking into consideration the `.5` margin on the page. You can also use `scale:` for the resizing of the image but I found it lacking precision. More information regarding this can be found in the [Prawn](http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf) manual

Answer (score 0):

You can get the page dimensions by using:

```
pdf_prawn.bounds.width
pdf_prawn.bounds.height
```

You can pass those to fit.